# Invalid Email message is not showing in login page in magento

Tags: magento

I'm currently working on making a login form in home page.
but after each invalid attempt the messages are not showing in proper place

i.e
The "invalid email and password " message showing in account dashboard and forgotpassword page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line in my template and it works:

```
<?php $message1=Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()
        ->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') 
        ->getMessages(true))->getGroupedHtml() ; ?>
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have forgot to call group messages block in your template

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

Comment: No i added that line but its not working. Actually i hav made my cms page as a login page. As i'm new to magento i can't feagure out how the session works with error messages

Comment: @mak so, where did you added this line?

Comment: now got my solution  added the following line to my template .                                           <?php $message1=Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->
  thanks for the help.   setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
     ->getMessages(true))->getGroupedHtml() ;
?>

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have forgot to call messages block in your template. add this code , its work for me

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
```